# Query relations between subclasses of two given classes

Tags: sparql, dbpedia, rdfs

I would like to get all relations between a Person and a Movie, where anything that is subclass of Person is also a Person (an actor, for example)

This is my attempt:

```
SELECT ?property ?film WHERE 
{
  {
    ?property rdf:type owl:ObjectProperty;
              rdfs:range ?person;
              rdfs:domain ?film.
    ?person rdfs:subclassOf* dbo:Person.
    ?film rdfs:subclassOf* dbo:Work.
  } UNION 
  {
    ?property rdf:type owl:ObjectProperty;
              rdfs:domain ?person;
              rdfs:range ?film.
    ?person rdfs:subclassOf* dbo:Person.
    ?film rdfs:subclassOf* dbo:Work. 
  }
}
```

With [results](http://dbpedia.org/snorql/?query=SELECT%20%3Fproperty%20%3Ffilm%20%3Fperson%20WHERE%20%0D%0A%7B%0D%0A%20%20%7B%0D%0A%20%20%20%20%3Fproperty%20rdf%3Atype%20owl%3AObjectProperty%3B%0D%0A%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20rdfs%3Arange%20%3Fperson%3B%0D%0A%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20rdfs%3Adomain%20%3Ffilm.%0D%0A%20%20%20%20%3Fperson%20rdfs%3AsubclassOf*%20dbo%3APerson.%0D%0A%20%20%20%20%3Ffilm%20rdfs%3AsubclassOf*%20dbo%3AWork.%0D%0A%20%20%7D%20UNION%20%0D%0A%20%20%7B%0D%0A%20%20%20%20%3Fproperty%20rdf%3Atype%20owl%3AObjectProperty%3B%0D%0A%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20rdfs%3Adomain%20%3Fperson%3B%0D%0A%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20rdfs%3Arange%20%3Ffilm.%0D%0A%20%20%20%20%3Fperson%20rdfs%3AsubclassOf*%20dbo%3APerson.%0D%0A%20%20%20%20%3Ffilm%20rdfs%3AsubclassOf*%20dbo%3AWork.%0D%0A%20%20%7D%0D%0A%7D%0D%0A):

```
SPARQL results:
property    film    person
dbpedia:ontology/author [http]  dbpedia:ontology/Work [http]    dbpedia:ontology/Person [http]
dbpedia:ontology/chiefEditor [http] dbpedia:ontology/Work [http]    dbpedia:ontology/Person [http]
dbpedia:ontology/composer [http]    dbpedia:ontology/Work [http]    dbpedia:ontology/Person [http]
dbpedia:ontology/coverArtist [http] dbpedia:ontology/Work [http]    dbpedia:ontology/Person [http]
dbpedia:ontology/mainCharacter [http]   dbpedia:ontology/Work [http]    dbpedia:ontology/Person [http]
dbpedia:ontology/narrator [http]    dbpedia:ontology/Work [http]    dbpedia:ontology/Person [http]
dbpedia:ontology/translator [http]  dbpedia:ontology/Work [http]    dbpedia:ontology/Person [http]
dbpedia:ontology/writer [http]  dbpedia:ontology/Work [http]    dbpedia:ontology/Person [http]
dbpedia:ontology/created [http] dbpedia:ontology/Work [http]    dbpedia:ontology/Person [http]
dbpedia:ontology/debutWork [http]   dbpedia:ontology/Work [http]    dbpedia:ontology/Person [http]
dbpedia:ontology/notableWork [http] dbpedia:ontology/Work [http]    dbpedia:ontology/Person [http]
```

However all results have as range/domain Person/Film and no subclasses. I would expect http://dbpedia.org/ontology/starring to be a result, since its domain is `Actor` and range `Work`

Why is my query failing? Can someone point my mistake?

Thanks in advance

Comment: Indeed, the property is `rdfs:subClassOf` (https://www.w3.org/TR/rdf-schema/#ch_subclassof). As I understand you are not interested to see what properties are used, but all properties that a defined with this range. This will exclude many properties from the results. At the same time you are interested in film, but using the broader class `dbo:Work` would also bring books etc.

Comment: Right. As Ivo said, you have a typo: rdfs:sub**C**lassOf

Comment: Your query will get you the defined properties but not all that are actually used. For example, you results exclude http://dbpedia.org/ontology/lastAppearance among others.